# Elasticsearch: get exact matches then fuzzy matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that this question has been asked and answered in several posts but having tried most of them, I has to ask it here.

I am looking to get exact matches first, followed by fuzzy matches.

```
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query":req.params.name,
            "fuzziness" : 1
          }
        }
      }
      ,
      {
        "match_phrase": {
            "name": {
              "query": req.params.name
            }
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [
    {
      "match": {
        "name": {
          "query":req.params.name,
          "boost": 5
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

What I am getting right now is fuzzy matches showing earlier than exact.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: To understand why fuzzy matches are scored higher, you should pass `?explain=true` param with your search. It will give you a detailed breakdown of the scores for your hits. Supplement that with this doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html
It should be apparent that the fuzzy matches are being scored higher due to a higher component from IDF (Inverse document frequency). Having understood the reason behind the scores, you can maybe split your query into two constant_score queries, one for fuzzy, the other for match or disable IDF completely?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts here. I will try that out.